# Sort varchar integers first in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sql-order-by

I wrote this code to show datas from a wordpress database table in a html table:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'mytable';
$stats = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY cast(alexacr as UNSIGNED) ASC");
$itemnum = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM $table_name");
echo '<span style="font-family: sans-serif;position:relative;float: left;font-size: 18px;"><em>'.$itemnum.' Sites</em></span>';
echo '<table>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<th>Nome &amp; Link</th><th>Alexa CR</th>';
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
foreach ($stats as $stat){
echo'<tr>';
echo '<td><a title="'.str_replace('_','',$stat->name).'" href="'.$stat->url.'" target="_blank">'.str_replace('_','',$stat->name).'</a></td><td>'.$stat->alexacr.'</td>';
echo'</tr>';
 }
echo '</tbody>'; 
echo '</table>';
```

alexacr column is set to varchar.
The result for alexacr column is like this:

```
N/A
1
2
3
4
```

How can i sort only numbers to be so?

```
1
2
3
4
N/A
```

Thanks.

Comment: Store numbers as numbers, use `NULL` for N/A may be?

Comment: Can you explain better, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  SELECT 
        *
  FROM 
        Table1
  Order By 
        CASE WHEN alexacr like 'N/A' then 1 else 0 end ASC,
        LPAD(alexacr, 20, '0') ASC
```

demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/210007/1

more details for LPAD at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

Comment: If i replace 1,2,3,4 with numbers of different length not works.Thanks.

Comment: I think it works only if i have numbers of max 3 length but if i use for example 4580 not works.But now i know a new function, thanks.

Comment: please check now, tested up to 10 digits

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY alexacr ,alexacr *1
```

Edit

i guess n/a is a NULL so

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN alexacr IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,alexacr
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9ce3/2)

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b080f/3)

Comment: @Mr.M I seriously doubt that

Comment: N/A isn't null. When i try to use first code with great numbers(1212,12632,2185,319) not works.Thanks.